# foreign key same table constraint with .net DataAdapter

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, dataadapter

I'm trying to add a number of rows to a DataTable and use a DataAdapter to write the table to the database.
The database table in question has a self-reference (ParentId) with a foreign key.
The set of rows I'm trying to insert contains parents and their children. I'm adding the rows in the correct order, so that the parent rows are added first.
Nevertheless I get a "foreign key same table constraint violation" upon calling update on the DataAdapter.
I guess the adapter just doesn't care about the order in which the rows are inserted into the database.
Is there a solution other than disabling the constraints before update?

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

Insert the parent rows, call update, then insert the child rows.

Comment: I've considered that, but would really like to have as few round-trips to the database as possible :)

Comment: Is the primary key an identity column?

Comment: Can you show some code, specifically your adapter's Insert command definition and where you add rows to the datatable and calling the update.